# Listview Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout

I want to create a layout and it is  using listview jut like this :

[image]

This layout is dynamic so it is using listview but I am not sure how to use that white bar image on left side of design. How to use it in `listview`. Please help.

Comment: add that bar in your list view item

Comment: But it will take gap according to all items

Comment: from your screen shot , it can be implemented easily

Comment: How, Can you help me if possible?

Comment: did you try answer below. if below library did not help you then I tell you how to do

Comment: I tried but it does not help me as I want. Can you help?

Comment: I find Timeline-View helpful for you. It uses Recyclerview so you can easily implement it .

Comment: but I want same bar for all

Comment: see this: https://github.com/alorma/TimelineView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/item_main.xml   and run their sample app. you can make same layout as you want

Answer (score 1):

How about these libraries?

1) [Timeline-View](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View)

[image]

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.5'
}
```

2) [TimelineView](https://github.com/alorma/TimelineView)

[image]

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.alorma:timelineview:2.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

Try this way to make **exactly like** your **row xml** of adapter and make changes as per your need:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/white_empty_round" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/car_wheel" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Criminal Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_crime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Crime : "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_crime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="Details"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also **add the drawable xml** for empty round in bar line:-
**`white_empty_round.xml`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="#fff" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but i want to attach all bars but it will create margin in bars

Comment: Just remove `android:paddingTop="5dp"` and `android:paddingBottom="5dp"` from main parent(root) `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @DeepanshiGupta Also I have `Update` the answer. Check it.

Comment: @DeepanshiGupta If this answer solve your problem, accept this as answer.